# Сравнием 2 строки через аргументы командной строки

Tags: java, строки, командная-строка

Суть в чем, я через аргументы командной строки буду подавать 2 строки, программа должна сравнить их и вывести результат, но к сожалению вылетает ошибка, скорее всего я неправильно использую указатель на аргумент

```
public class str_cmp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String str1 = args[0];
String str2 = args[1];
if (str1.equals(str2))
    System.out.println("OK");
else
    System.out.println("KO");
}
```

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at str_cmp.main(str_cmp.java:4)
соответственно какая ошибка вылетает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я бы предложил так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = args[0];
    String str2 = args[1];
    if (args.length > 1 && str1.equals(str2))
        System.out.println("OK");
    else
        System.out.println("KO");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит что индек вышел за границы массива. Скорее всего вы ввели один или не ввели их вовсе ожидая ввода двух параметров. Для точности добавьте командную строку которую вы ввели.

Потренируйтесь с вводом параметров для начала на этом примере

```
public class str_cmp {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  for (String str : args){
    System.out.println(str);
  }
 }
}
```

Данный пример выведет каждый переданный параметр в командной строке на новой строчке.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю. что мы компилируем через javac str_cmp.java 
затем java str_cmp + cюда пишем аргументы по очереди, но почему-то не находит файл .class

в idea все работает, но через командную строку что-то невероятное происходит

Comment: @MarzepanioTortus это не совсем то. javac - это компилятор java файлов. вам нужно запускать через java почитайте тут https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-java-commands

Comment: Если не находит файл .class то это значит что в командной строке вы не указали точный путь к скомпилированому .class файлу, делается это через команду для командной строки а именно cd после чего указываете путь к файлу.

Comment: Так я нахожусь в этой же директории ведь...у меня не получается сделать так только на винде, на убунту все легко залетает ))